# What is the origin of the word "comorbid"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Is the meaning just as I literally read it, i.e. 'awful and occurring at the same time'?

Can it apply to things outside of medicine that are also awful and occurring at the same time? Why or why not?

If possible, I'm interested in more detail than the [dictionary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comorbid) can tell me.

Comment: It comes from the technical definition of [*morbid*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morbid), not the popular one, so the dictionary entry for that word is also relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Morbid* means abnormal and unhealthy. In common parlance its used for things that are gruesome, horrifying -- as you say "awful". As an example, take the following from [*The Corpse: A History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pSjTAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22morbid%20fascination%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8lJSu0sfOAhWE6iYKHeliBxwQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22morbid%20fascination%22&f=false) by C Quigley:

> We arrive in droves as the bodies of murder victims are removed from
>   the yard of a rural home, partly out of **morbid** fascination and partly
>   to steel ourselves and each other against the mounting horror.

In medical terms abnormal and unhealthy simply means diseased, and the word is used to describe disease and disease process. Thus from [*New York Medical Journal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ctA6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA781&dq=%22morbid%20condition%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-mc2A1MfOAhXOMx4KHerXAtgQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22morbid%20condition%22&f=false), Volume 113 (May 18, 1921):

> The **morbid** condition induced by compressive injury is twofold: it
>   consists of the direct injury to the tissue at the time the force is
>   applied, and the additional injury caused by the increased tension
>   within the tissue,....

But people sometimes have more than one disease at a time, so the medical profession uses the term of art *comorbid* to describe such a circumstance.  For instance from *Cancer in the Elderly: Approaches to Early Detection and Treatment* by R Yancik:

> At issue is whether women with breast cancer and arthritis report
>   poorer quality of life than women with only breast cancer, or breast
>   cancer and some other **comorbid** condition.

Here the comparison is between patients with breast cancer only, those with breast cancer and arthritis, and those with breast cancer and some disease other than arthritis.

A look at the Ngram viewer and a brief dance with the google shows that *comorbid* is trapped in its role as a medical term of art. There's nothing that prevents you from using it in a non-medical context, but you would be a pioneer.

Comment: As a non-medic whose science reading occasionally includes medical matters, I  hadn't come across it. I was familiar with the noun form co-morbidity. While the hyphenated form isn't the most common, it might be clearer, at least once you've established the medical meaning of morbidity.

Comment: This is exactly the type of context I was hoping to learn. Thank you for this vastly informative post! And for ending my read with a laugh.

Answer (score 0):

***[Comorbid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/comorbid)*** is a recent back-formation from ***[comorbidity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=comorbidity):***

> - 1985, from co- "along with" + morbidity "diseased condition." Comorbid (adj.) is a 1990 back-formation.

(Etymonline)

Comment: The Ngram viewer has examples of both in print from the mid-'80s.

Comment: @deadrat - the earliest I can see is from 1989, earlier usage is not clear from Ngram. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comorbid&year_start=1980&year_end=1990&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomorbid%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *Comorbid* here from 1984: https://books.google.com/books?id=zgiGrm-dFrQC&q=%22comorbid%22&dq=%22comorbid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8mKPD7cfOAhVB5iYKHX-KDk84KBDoAQgeMAE

Comment: Unluckily the relevant snippets are not available, but there may be earlier instances.